# Is there a tool to dump a Neo4j graph as Cypher and re-load it from Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, mysql, cypher

Everyone familiar with MySQL has likely used the mysqldump command which can generate a file of SQL statements representing both the schema and data in a MySQL database.
These SQL text files are commonly used for many purposes: backups, seeding replicas, copying databases between installations (- copy prod DBs to staging environments etc) and others.

Is there a similar tool for Neo4j that can dump an entire graph into a text file of Cypher statements, that when executed on an empty database would reconstruct the original data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In neo4j version 2 (e.g. 2.0.0M3), using neo4j-shell, you can use the command

`dump`

which will create the cypher statements (pretty much like mysqldump would do. To read in the file you can use

`cat dump.cql | neo4j-shell`

Comment: This work, but it is very slow.  Is there a way to make the cypher creation much faster?

Comment: It's in one transaction? Why size of my db is not increasing?

Comment: QueryExecutionKernelException: Invalid input 'c': expected whitespace, comment, ';' or end of input (line 2, column 1 (offset: 60))
"create constraint on (n:`target`) assert n.`type` is unique"
 ^

Answer (score 5):

`Cypher` is just a query language for Neo4J just as `SQL` is for `MySQL` or other relational databases. If you wish to transfer the db, then you just need to copy the folder containing the database files. Simple.

For example my folder `simple-graph` contains all the db files. Just copy the folder and store it at some other location. You can directly start using it as:

```
GraphDatabaseServiceraphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(DB_PATH);//DB_PATH is path to the new location
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the procedure `apoc.export.cypher.all()` to dump all the data in your database.

For example, you can dump the database into a single file called `dump-file.cypher`:

```
neo4j@neo4j> CALL apoc.export.cypher.all('dump-file.cypher');
```

For details of the procedure, please see the documentation: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.export/apoc.export.cypher.all/.